# Save edits using a form Python action

Tags: pyqgis

I'm trying to implement a couple of Python actions so that you can start editing an object and save the changes from the id form.

[image: Start edit acion]

I have had no problems adding the start edit action. However, saving the changes does not save the modifications that are made to the form.

```
from qgis.PyQt import QtWidgets
from qgis.gui import QgsAttributeForm

project = QgsProject.instance()
vl = QgsProject.instance().mapLayer('[% @layer_id %]')

vl.commitChanges()

QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(None,u'Edición de registro [% $id %]'
,u'Registro guardado')
```

[image]

I have looked for the option to retrieve the form values ​​but I have not succeeded.

Some help?